# Integer division in Common Lisp

Tags: common-lisp, integer-division

I tried to do division in Lisp.
When I do `(/ 5 2)`, the result is `5/2`,
but what I need is `2`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 8):

The function call

```
(floor 5 2)
```

will return the result of the integer division 2 and the remainder 1.

[Description](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_floorc.htm#floor) in the Common Lisp Hyperspec

Comment: I needed to store the result in a variable and it works, thank you